# JArray - get all values from specific param

Tags: c#, arrays, json, .net-core, json.net

I receive a JArray object from a front-end edit control. I want to retrieve and concatenate all "text" values.

The ideal result should be a string:

"Established in 1995, the Elephant Sanctuary in Tennessee has provided ...spans 2,700 acres. This is underlined text. This is italic text. This is bold text"

```
[
  {
    "type": "paragraph",
    "attrs": {
      "style": null,
      "class": null,
      "id": null
    },
    "content": [
      {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "Established in 1995, the Elephant Sanctuary in Tennessee has provided ..."
      },
      {
        "type": "text",
        "marks": [
          {
            "type": "strong"
          }
        ],
        "text": "spans 2,700 acres."
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "paragraph",
    "attrs": {
      "style": null,
      "class": null,
      "id": null
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "paragraph",
    "attrs": {
      "style": null,
      "class": null,
      "id": null
    },
    "content": [
      {
        "type": "text",
        "marks": [
          {
            "type": "u"
          }
        ],
        "text": "This is underlined text."
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "paragraph",
    "attrs": {
      "style": null,
      "class": null,
      "id": null
    },
    "content": [
      {
        "type": "text",
        "marks": [
          {
            "type": "em"
          }
        ],
        "text": "This is italic text."
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "paragraph",
    "attrs": {
      "style": null,
      "class": null,
      "id": null
    },
    "content": [
      {
        "type": "text",
        "marks": [
          {
            "type": "strong"
          }
        ],
        "text": "This is bold text"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far pls?

Comment: with JSON.NET  => `JArray.Parse` + `JToken.SelectTokens` +  `string.Join`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [JSONPath](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm):

```
var jArray = JArray.Parse(json);

var s = string.Join(".", jArray.SelectTokens("$..text"));
```

[Here](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html#e2) a list of expression you can use.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
string text = string.Join(" ", JArray.Parse(json).Where(j => j["content"] != null)
                    .SelectMany(j => j["content"].Select(i => (string) i["text"])));
```